# iOS 8 Swift Audio Playback Execute Method On Completion

Tags: swift, ios8

I am playing an audio file in Swift for iOS 8.  I need to be able to know when the sound is finished.  How can I have a method executed when the sound is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you're playing it. Look for a delegate method, a notification, or an observable property whose state change can trigger a KVO notification.

For example, if you're using an AVAudioPlayer, its `delegate` gets notified by a delegate method, which you can find out about here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008068

Comment: The delegate method is what I'm looking for.  I implemented the method shown on the Apple page but it doesn't get called.  Here's my code:
[p]
Loading the sound file:
var introSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("intro", ofType: "wav")!)

Playing the sound:
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundResource, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer.play()

Delegate method:
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!,
        successfully flag: Bool) {
            println("finished")
    }

Comment: It doesn't get called because you are not the `delegate`. You have to be the `delegate` if you want to be sent a delegate method.

Comment: Here's some working example code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p643ducking/ch27p912ducking/Player.swift